# Python versus C++

Tags: c++

Olá, sou programador iniciante. Escrevi um programa para processamento de imagens em Python que funcionou perfeitamente, embora sua execução seja muito lenta, em virtude do grande número de operações envolvidas. Resolvi transcrever o mesmo programa para C++ e consegui com sucesso compilá-lo e executá-lo. Contudo, a execução em C++ não obteve o mesmo resultado, gerando uma figura um pouco diferente do obtido pelo Python. Já conferi minuciosamente e, aparentemente, não há erros na transcrição do Python para o C++. Pergunto, é possível, em virtude das diferenças na estrutura das duas linguagens, haver diferenças nos resultados obtidos?

Comment: A sua pergunta já não afirma que é possível haver diferenças nos resultados obtidos?

Comment: Sem podermos comparar os algoritmos utilizados entre A e B não tem como lhe ajudar.

Comment: Não somente nas diferenças das linguagens como principalmente na limitação do desenvolvedor em ambas as linguagens. Sabendo que são linguagens diferentes, as soluções serão diferentes. Simplesmente não pode transcrever um código da linguagem A para a linguagem B, ipsis litteris, esperando o mesmo resultado. Dada minha humilde experiência em Python, eu diria que é mais provável que a demora seja devido algum erro de implementação do que limitação da própria linguagem.

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a documentação do **OpenCV**

> **How OpenCV-Python bindings are generated?**
>
> In OpenCV, all algorithms are implemented in C++. But these algorithms
>   can be used from different languages like Python, Java etc. This is
>   made possible by the bindings generators. These generators create a
>   bridge between C++ and Python which enables users to call C++
>   functions from Python.
>   (https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/da/d49/tutorial_py_bindings_basics.html)

Logo como a documentação diz, as implementações de OpenCV em Python e C++ utilizam o mesmo código core, contudo pode sim haver alguma estrutura de dados que sofra algum tipo de arrendondamento diferente entre as linguagens gerando resultados minimamente distintos, ou algum outro tipo de anomalia, mas isso provavelmente ocorreria fora do contexto do OpenCV.

Para analise da situação precisaríamos das implementações em ambas as linguagens.